# Some information about Spring converters and how Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter work in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, converters

I have some question for you about Spring MVC message converters use.

If I have the following situation:

In my view I have the following link:

```
 <a id="writeXmlAccept" class="writeXmlLink" href="<c:url value="/messageconverters/xml" />">Write XML via Accept=application/xml</a>
```

This link generetes an HTTP Request towards the URL: **"/messageconverters/xml"**

Related to click event of this link having **class="writeXmlLink"** I have the following Jquery callback function:

```
$("a.writeXmlLink").click(function() {
    /* Variabile che contiene il riferimento all'elemento nel DOM che ha 
       scatenato l'evento click (il link clickato) */
    var link = $(this);     

    // Viene eseguita la chiamata ajax 
    $.ajax({ 
        // Indirizzo verso cui è indirizzata la richiesta 
        url: link.attr("href"),     
        /* Prima di inviare l'HTTP Request esegui la funzione passandogli il
           parametro req che rappresenta l'HTTP Request */
        beforeSend: function(req) { 
            // Se l'url termina con .xml 
            if (!this.url.match(/\.xml$/)) {
              // Aggiunge alla HTTP Request l'header Accept: application/xml 
                req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");       
            }

        },
        success: function(xml) {        // Caso di successo: 
            MvcUtil.showSuccessResponse(MvcUtil.xmlencode(xml), link);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {          // Caso di errore: 
            MvcUtil.showErrorResponse(xhr.responseText, link);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Since the URL **"/messageconverters/xml"** doesn't end with *.xml pattern, the `if` body is not executed and the `Accept` header is not set in this request

Ok, so this function only executes the ajax call of my HTTP Request and wait for a response.

The method of my controller class that handles this HTTP Request is the following one:

```
/* Metodo che gestisce HTTP Request di tipo GET dirette verso 
 * l'URL: "/messageconverters/xml" */
@RequestMapping(value="/xml", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody JavaBean writeXml() {
    return new JavaBean("bar", "apple");
}
```

This method only creates and returns a new JavaBean object valorizing it's tow properties

JavaBean is a class of my example that have only 2 properties, the getter and setter method and the toString() method, this one:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JavaBean {

    @NotNull
    private String foo;

    @NotNull
    private String fruit;

    public JavaBean() {
    }

    public JavaBean(String foo, String fruit) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }
        // GETTER & SETTER & toString()
}
```

So the valorized JavaBean object is returned to the client (the browser) that show the following output in my view:

```
<javaBean><foo>bar</foo><fruit>apple</fruit></javaBean>
```

I would understand well when and how the converters work in this example:

I think that the used converter is **`Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`** because I am writing an XML code inside my view and because my JavaBean class is annoted using `@XmlRootElement` annotation that is a JAXB annotation that implement the mapping between a Java class and an XML field.

So, when I click on my link what happens?

The valorized JavaBean object is created and when I return it (inside the body field of the HTTP Response) this JavaBean object is converted into an XML document by the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tool like FireBug, see the exact request and response headers. It will make things easier.

I suspect the response does not have the correct content type or MIME type i.e. it should be `application/xml` or `text/xml`.

You need to specify the response content type in your controller method. To do this, simply assign the content type value(s) to the `produces` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

e.g. is available in the spring documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Hope this helps.